# Python, use variable as object "name"

Tags: python-2.7

I've been getting into Python for a while now, since I'm still a beginner, I try to keep things simple as much as possible. There is however one thing that I would like to be able to do, but cannot get right.

I've searched and found several questions that somewhat resemble, mine, but answers are mostly to use `eval()` and `exec()`, which I read is very bad practice. Using a dictionary seems to be another often proposed option, but I don't see how to apply this to my case.

```
class pthead:

    def __init__(self, name, port):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port

    def initialize(self):
            ser4.write(initialization_commands)  # works
            (self.port).write(initialization_commands)  # doesn't work


UART.setup("UART4")
ser4 = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyO4", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

head = pthead("kop", "ser4")
head.initialize()
```

Is it really that hard to use the variable as an object (hope I get the terminology right)? I can hardly believe it is not a common thing to do, for example after user input...

I'm using python 2.7 (for legacy purposes).

Comment: Use this `head = pthead("kop", ser4)` it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using it correctly. The port you are supplying isn't a port but a string `"ser4".

```
class pthead:

    def __init__(self, name, port):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port

    def initialize(self):
        self.port.write(initialization_commands)  # it will work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    UART.setup("UART4")
    ser4 = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyO4", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

    head = pthead("kop", ser4) #supplying port as second argument
    head.initialize()
```

Comment: That does indeed work when used in a script. In interactive mode (where I tried out different options), that wasn't the case... 
`x = pthead("name", ser4)` returns `"NameError: name 'ser4' is not defined"`

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD  If you are using it as a script then you need to provide a port value of ser4 there.Since you want to supply your provide port you need to define it before in the code then pass it as an argument.

Comment: The code outside the class is what you need to put in the other file while importing phead

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my reply. It does work when I run it as a script, but if I start interactive mode, then `from foo import pthead` and try to create an instance with `x = pthead("name", ser4)` I get the `"NameError: name 'ser4' is not defined"`error if I do not put quotes around the port.

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD I got you but you haven't made your program like that you are supplying name and a port. You need to carryout changes either your `__init__` function should take `name` and a `port` value as argument but here you are essentially using `port ` variable as argument

Comment: For creating instance you will have to `import phead` and then use `UART.setup("UART4")
    ser4 = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyO4", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

    head = pthead("kop", ser4) ` these lines